# NodeJS Leaflet with multiple layers from PostGIS Query

Tags: node.js, leaflet, postgis

Working on a new mapping project using Nodejs, leaflet, and PostGIS. At this point I'm able to load and display the map tile layer along with our sales reps zones from Postgis. Now I'm trying to add another layer that will display all US Counties, also stored in Postgresql. Both Postgis queries run and display when used separately but I cannot get both to load and display together. Here's an excerpt from nodejs 'routes/index.js':

```
router.get('/map', function(req, res) {
var client = new pg.Client(conString); // Setup our Postgres Client
client.connect(); // connect to the client
var query = client.query(zone_query); // Run our Query
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});
// Pass the result to the map page
query.on("end", function (result) {
    var data = result.rows[0].row_to_json; // Save the JSON as variable data
    res.render('map', {
        title: "Express API", // Give a title to our page
        zoneData: data // Pass data to the View
    });
});
});

router.get('/map', function(req, res) {
var client = new pg.Client(conString); // Setup our Postgres Client
client.connect(); // connect to the client
var query = client.query(counties_query); // Run our Query
query.on("row", function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});
// Pass the result to the map page
query.on("end", function (result) {
    var data2 = result.rows[0].row_to_json; // Save the JSON as variable data
    res.render('map', {
        title: "Express API", // Give a title to our page
        countyData: data2 // Pass data to the View
    });
});
});
```

And from the 'view/map.pug':

```
    script("text/javascript").
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var myData = !{JSON.stringify(zoneData)};
        var cntyData = !{JSON.stringify(countyData)};
        // Create variable to hold map element, give initial settings to map
        var map = L.map('map',{
            center: [39.7799642, -86.2728367],
            zoom: 6,
            //layers: [zones, counties]
        });
```

... and then further down:

```
L.geoJson(myData,{
            style: zoneStyle,

            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                var ofc = JSON.stringify(feature.properties.office);
                var zn = JSON.stringify(feature.properties.zone);
                layer.bindPopup("office: " + ofc + "<br>" + "zone #" + zn);
               // layer.bindPopup("Zone #"+JSON.stringify(feature.properties.zone));
            }
        }).addTo(map);

        // Add county data to map
        L.geoJson(cntyData,{
            onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
                //var desc = JSON.stringify(feature.properties.descriptio);
                layer.bindPopup(desc);
            }
        }).addTo(map);
```

Any one of these works perfectly by itself but trying to load both layers displays nothing at all. Ultimately what I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to toggle the sales zones and state county boundary layers on and off.

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: You're using the variable name `query` for both PGSQL queries, which might be causing some collisions internally. Use different names, or use closures.

Comment: On top of that, you're trying to `res.render()` twice. My node.js is a bit rusty, so make extra sure that doing so makes sense in Express.

Comment: It's very likely that the first call to `res.render()` returns all the HTML to the browser, and closes the request-response stream in the express side of things, making one of the `res.render()`  calls to fail silently.

Comment: Okay, even with my limited experience with nodejs, leaflet, and postgis, that all makes sense. From what I understand I can pass multiple variables in `res.render()` but I guess I'm still a little confused as to how to get those query results into the `res.render()` function?

Comment: Something like one call to `res.render('map', {title:"foo", zoneData: z, countyData: c})`

Comment: That part I understand. The problem is running two separate queries,  looping through each of those and then passing those to `res.render`. I didn't know if each of these should be separate functions or can I pass both into `query.on("end", function (result, result1) {...`

Comment: You don't loop anything. This is asynchronous, so you set up your callbacks in such a way that you run `res.render` when both have finished. No matter the order. Use the [`async` lib](https://caolan.github.io/async/) if too many callbacks are becoming confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was having the same problem and come up with this solution with the help of some colleagues.

```
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
var client = new pg.Client(conString); // Setup our Postgres Client
client.connect(); // connect to the client

// creating an empty array for my row_to_json queries
var data = []

var resto_query = client.query(restoPoint_query); //connects to postgres so it can query up my request
resto_query.on("row", function (row, result) {
result.addRow(row);
});
resto_query.on("end", function (result) {
var resto_to_json = result.rows[0].row_to_json; // Save the JSON as variable data
data.push(resto_to_json); // push JSON data to data[]

var barrierQuery = client.query(barrier_query);
barrierQuery.on("row", function (row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
});
barrierQuery.on("end", function (result) {
    var barrier_to_json = result.rows[0].row_to_json;
    data.push(barrier_to_json);

    res.render('map', {
      title: "Leaflet Test API", // Give a title to our page
      resto_point: data[0], // Pass data to the View
      barrier: data[1]
```

Probably not the best solution but it works for the time being.

Comment: Sorry for lack of response, got pulled off into other projects but I'm now back onto this one. Anthony, I'll give your code a try and report back. And thanks for the input.

Comment: You are very welcome. If you figure out a better way to load in the layer, please share.

Comment: Blowing the dust off of this since we're back on this project. Tried the example above but did not work. Looking at the web console (browser dev tools) shows that no data from either query was passed to the page displayed. In my limited knowledge of programming I'm wondering if "data.push" isn't where things are going wrong?

Comment: Here's what I have so far
    /* County layer */
  var county_query = client.query(counties_query);
  county_query.on("row", function(row, result) {
    result.addRow(row);
  });
  county_query.on("end", function(result) {
    var counties_to_json = result.rows[0].row_to_json;
    data.push(counties_to_json);
  });

Comment: After much persistence, trial and error, got it to work. Thanks to Anthony for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.